# Find SD card path for android

Tags: android

My phone has its SD card path named as "/storage/external_SD"

But I hear different phone manufacturers name their paths differently. Like SD_card , externalMemory etc..

I am developing an app that opens the SD card contents when a filechooser is opened.

How can I set a path to open when different brands name their sd card paths differently ?

Answer (score 1):

`getExternalStorageDirectory ()` will give you the path to (usually) an SD card, so you can you this in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`Environment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html) class and its static method [`getExternalStorageDirectory`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()).

> Return the primary external storage directory.
>   ...
>   In devices with multiple "external" storage directories, this directory represents the
>   "primary" external storage that the user will interact with. Access to
>   secondary storage is available through

Comment: I used it. It only gives the internal memory. The emulated one to be more precise. This method returns "/storage/emulated/0" and not the desired "storage/external_SD" . So that method will not solve my problem im facing.

Comment: Try `System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE")` and see what you get :)